# Keep getting int cannot be converted to int[]

Tags: java

With the below code, I keep getting the following error message:

> int cannot be converted to int[]

Here is my function:

```
public static void populateTestScores(String[] names, int [][] scores)
{    
    for(int j = 0; j < scores.length; j++)
    {
        out.println("Enter Test Scores " + (j + 1) + ": ");
        scores[j] = user.nextInt();
    }
}
```

How would I correct this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: What is your actual problem???

Comment: So, what do you not understand about the error message?  Java is a strongly typed language, so you cannot assign an `int` value to a `int[]` variable.

Comment: Presumably `user.nextInt()` returns an integer.  But you are trying to store it in something that expects an array of integers.  An apple is not a basket of apples.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: `int[][]` is an array of `int[]`. You're treating it as though it were an array of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`scores` is an array of arrays (or a matrix, if you like).

When you iterate through `scores` using your `for` loop, each time you take a value from `scores`, what will you get? Think about it - if you have a list of lists - each thing in it will be a list, right?

As your code is written, you may have to change more than one or two words to fix - here are some possibilities:

1. `scores` is actually just a list of integers - in this case it is defined wrong
2. `scores` is defined correctly - in this case you need a nested loop if you want to access each cell in it

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an integer (`user.nextInt()`) to a 2-dimensional array element i.e. an array. This can't be done.

Either you need to convert `scores` to uni-dimensional array like so `int[] scores`, or need to make a loop to retrieve a series of ints into an array like so (roughly):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    ints.add(s.nextInt());
    System.out.print("another int ? ");
}
scores[j] = ints.toArray();
```